# Tensorboard with pytorch dont display a graph

Tags: deep-learning, visualization, pytorch, convolutional-neural-network

I am trying to visualize a model I created using Tensorboard with Pytorch but when running tensorboard and going to the graph tab nothing is shown, im adding my code for reference, also im adding a screen-shot of my conda env for all the dependencies

```
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter 

writer = SummaryWriter()
images, labels = next(iter(trainloader))
grid = torchvision.utils.make_grid(images)

writer.add_image('images', grid)
writer.add_graph(model=model, input_to_model=images, verbose=True)
writer.close()
```

[image: Conda env running the code]

[image: Screenshot of the tensorboard trying to display my model graph]

Comment: This question is probably better suited for stack-overflow, where you have a `tensorboard` tag (and a bigger community).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
Check out this thread:
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/24157

TLDR: Update PyTorch to PyTorch-nightly and the problem should be solved.
https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/